# I want to change the position of rows of table

Tags: jquery

I am having data in the .php page inside a table in the form of various rows.
I want to facilitate that user can change the position of these rows by dragging the rows vertically.how it is possible using jQuery.

Suggest me some plugin or some tutorial link so that i can do so.

i am following this tutorial but i cannot figure out how to make the row position persistent in the databse.SO that next tiume when user came to that page he will see the same arrangement of  rows

I m using this tutorial http://www.isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/

Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the [Table Drag and Drop jQuery plugin](http://www.isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/) in the past. It works very well.

**Edit:** Added example

This is how I sent the new row order to the PHP script which saves it in the database:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Initialise the drag-and-drop
    $("#table3").tableDnD({
        // Set the action to perform when the mouse button is released
        onDrop: function(table, row) {
            $("#AjaxResult").load("list_sort.php?list_id=3&"+$.tableDnD.serialize());
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: ya man thanks i am also using the same now but can u help me to figure out how to make the position of rows persistent in databse.

Comment: @Abhishek Gupta: You have to give each `<tr>` the unique ID of the record you're displaying. That ID is what gets returned in the array. The `#AjaxResult` is to let the user know the new order was successfully saved, but I ended up removing it.

Answer (score 2):

this [article](http://www.webdesignbooth.com/15-great-jquery-plugins-for-better-table-manipulation/) may help u

[personally prefer](http://www.isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/)

Comment: hey you just gave a link by google it out,while the link is not having any such tutorial which facilitates drag and drop arrangement of rows in table .the tutorial simply describes the pagination stuff.

Comment: @abhishek i update my question. btw u alwasy need to google for any links.. this site is prefered  logical help